# Discord.py change presence

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Hello i am making a bot and i want to change the presence

I keep getting a error i was hoping someone could tell me what i am doing wrong

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
import asyncio
import chalk
import requests
import random

#Bot token
bottoken = "snip"
#Bot command prefix
commandprefix = "#"

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=commandprefix)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print ("Starting up")
    print ("My username is " + bot.user.name + " and i am running with the ID: " + bot.user.id)
    await self.bot.change_presence(game=discord.Game(name="Test", type=1))
    print ("Started")

change_presence( game=None, status=None, afk=False)

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def hello(ctx):
    await bot.say("hi")
    print ("hi Posted")

bot.run(bottoken)
```

and the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "thefilelocationonmypc", line 64, in <module>

change_presence( game=None, status=None, afk=False)

NameError: name 'change_presence' is not defined
```

Comment: Please post the full code required to reproduce this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right now you are trying to call a function named `change_presence`. Because you did not define the function, you are getting that error.

You need to do `await bot.change_presence` instead of just `change_presence` in order to use discord.py's `change_presence` function

Answer (score 1):

You're not defining the `change_presence` function.
To make it work, do this:

```
async def change_presence():
 print ("Starting up")
 print ("My username is " + bot.user.name + " and i am running with the ID: " + bot.user.id)
 await bot.change_presence(game=discord.Game(name="Test", type=1))
 print ("Started")

change_presence();
```

Hope this helped you! :)

Answer (score -2):

**Working code:**

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
import asyncio
import requests
import random

bottoken = "snip"
commandprefix = "#"

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=commandprefix)


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print ("Starting up")
    print ("My username is " + bot.user.name + " and i am running with the ID: " + bot.user.id)
    await bot.change_presence(game=discord.Game(name="Test", type=1))
    print ("Started")


@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def hello(ctx):
    await bot.say("hi")
    print ("hi Posted")


bot.run(bottoken)
```

Comment: You should read the question first, and give some brief what you did special in it.